# Rails 4 - Import CSV is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, csv, hash

In rails 4.2.4, I am trying to extract the data from `.csv` file and save it to the database. But right now extracted `row` from the file is in wrong format so that value is not getting save.

```
require 'csv'
filename = "#{asset.document.path}"
if File.exist?(filename)
  file = File.open(filename)
  if file
    CSV::parse(file)[1..-1].each do |row|
      User.create_data(row, admin)
    end
  end
end

def create_data(row, admin)
  usr = User.new
  usr.name = row[0] if row[0]
  usr.email = row[1] if row[1]
  usr.password = row[2] if row[2]
  user.save
end
```

Generated `row`'s data is like `["Sannidhi\tsannidhi@gmail.com\tsannidhi123@\t"]`. From this `row` I am not getting each values separately `Eg: row[0], row[1] & row[2]` to assign for related database fields.

How can I solve this CSV import issue? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CSV::parse(file)[1..-1].each do |row|
  row.shift.split("\t") unless row.blank?
  User.create_data(row, admin)
end
```

After this, you should be able to access:

```
row[0] #=> "Sannidhi"
row[1]
row[2]
```

Comment: I am getting this `undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass` error

Comment: @ShruthiR can you post what you have tried ? I guess you are doing it for a blank row.

Comment: As I mentioned above row is there `["Sannidhi\tsannidhi@gmail.com\tsannidhi123@\t"]`

Answer (score 1):

You CSV file uses `tab`s as column separators. You can pass your own column separator to `CSV` as a `col_sep` option. Even though other 2 answers will do the job, let `csv` do its job on its own:

```
CSV::parse(file, col_sep: "\t")[1..-1].each do |row|
  User.create_data(row, admin)
end
```

Also, consider using `headers` option to use the first line of the file as a header instead of `[1..-1]`:

```
CSV::parse(file, col_sep: "\t", headers: 'first_row').each do |row|
  User.create_data(row, admin)
end
```

Comment: How can I ignore header using `CSV::parse(file, col_sep: "\t", headers: 'first_row')`  ?

Comment: If you add `header: true`, the first line of your csv file will be ignored automatically.

Answer (score -2):

`CSV` stands for Comma Separated Value. It seems that your file is separated by spaces instead. Replace the tabs in your file by commas.